# How to add native ad in between my gridview items (RecyclerView)?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, native-ads

I have implemented a gridlayout using recycler view . I need to implement the native ad in between of the grid items. I tried it but i was getting the native ads on top of my gridview items.

```
public class Event_Discover_Combined_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Event_Discover_Combined_Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Event_Discover_Combined_Details> beanList;
private int itemCount;

public Event_Discover_Combined_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event_Discover_Combined_Details> beanList, int itemCount) {
    this.context = context;
    this.beanList = beanList;
    this.imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    this.itemCount = itemCount;

}

//int viewType ;
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position % 3 == 0) {
        return R.layout.native_ad_frame_layout;
    } else {
        if (beanList.get(position).getType() == ConstantUrl.TYPE_EVENT) {
            return R.layout.events_item;
        } else {
            return R.layout.discover_item;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Event_Discover_Combined_Adapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static ImageLoader imageLoader;
// public static ImageLoader imageLoader2;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Event_Discover_Combined_Adapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Event_Discover_Combined_Details bean = beanList.get(position);

    if (position % 3 == 0) {
        //Ad View
        //For Native Ads
        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID));

        //if (requestContentAds) {
        builder.forContentAd(new NativeContentAd.OnContentAdLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onContentAdLoaded(NativeContentAd ad) {
                NativeContentAdView adView = (NativeContentAdView) getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.native_ad_content, null);
                populateContentAdView(ad, adView);
                holder.frameLayout.removeAllViews();
                holder.frameLayout.addView(adView);
            }
        });
        //}

        AdLoader adLoader = builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to load native ad: "
                        + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).build();
        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    } else {
        //Normal View

        AppLog.Log("combine", "beanlist" + bean.getType());

        if (bean.getType() == ConstantUrl.TYPE_DISCOVER) {
            if (!bean.getDiscoverDetails().getIcon().equals(""))
                imageLoader.displayImage(bean.getDiscoverDetails().getIcon(),
                        holder.iv_discover_icon);

            holder.tv_author_name.setText(bean.getDiscoverDetails().getAuthor());
            holder.item_discover_descrip.setText(bean.getDiscoverDetails().getDescription());
            holder.tv_discover_heading.setText(bean.getDiscoverDetails().getTitle());

        } else if (bean.getType() == ConstantUrl.TYPE_EVENT) {
            if (!bean.getEventDetails().getIcon().equals(""))
                imageLoader.displayImage(bean.getEventDetails().getIcon(),
                        holder.event_icon);

  /*  holder.item_event_date.setText(bean.getStartDate());
    holder.item_event_time.setText(bean.getStartDate());*/
            try {
                Date date1 = AppUtils.getFormatedDate(bean.getEventDetails().getStartDate());

                String event_time = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", date1) + " " + context.getString(R.string.at_text) + " " + new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa").format(date1);

                // holder.item_event_date.setText((String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", date1));

                holder.item_event_date.setText(event_time);
                holder.item_event_time.setText(event_time);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            holder.item_event_heading.setText(bean.getEventDetails().getName());
            holder.item_event_descrip.setText(bean.getEventDetails().getDescription());

        }

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemCount;
}

// int count = 0;

public void setItemCount(int count) {

    this.itemCount = count;

}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    //For Discover
    public ImageView iv_discover_icon;
    MyTextView tv_author_name;
    MyTextView item_discover_descrip;
    MyTextView_medium tv_discover_heading;

    //For Events
    public ImageView event_icon;
    public MyTextView_medium item_event_time;
    MyTextView item_event_date;
    MyTextView item_event_descrip;
    MyTextView_medium item_event_heading;

    //For Native Ads
    FrameLayout frameLayout;

    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //For Discover
        iv_discover_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_discover_icon);
        tv_author_name = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_author_name);
        tv_discover_heading = (MyTextView_medium) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_discover_heading);
        item_discover_descrip = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_discover_descrip);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        //For Events
        event_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_icon);
        item_event_date = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_event_date);
        item_event_time = (MyTextView_medium) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_event_time);
        item_event_heading = (MyTextView_medium) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_event_heading);
        item_event_descrip = (MyTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_event_descrip);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        //For Native Ads
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fl_adplaceholder);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ((beanList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getType()) == ConstantUrl.TYPE_EVENT) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Events.class);
            i.putExtra("event_details", beanList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getEventDetails());
            context.startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(beanList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDiscoverDetails().getUrl()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

private LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater() {
    AppLog.Log("classmate5", "inside_getLayoutInflater" + LayoutInflater.from(context));
    return LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

private void populateContentAdView(NativeContentAd nativeContentAd,
                                   NativeContentAdView adView) {
    AppLog.Log("classmate5", "inside_populateContentAdView");
    adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_headline));
    adView.setImageView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_image));
    adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_body));
    adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_call_to_action));
    adView.setLogoView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_logo));
    adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_advertiser));

    // Some assets are guaranteed to be in every NativeContentAd.
    ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeContentAd.getHeadline());
    ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeContentAd.getBody());
    ((TextView) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeContentAd.getCallToAction());
    ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeContentAd.getAdvertiser());

    List<NativeAd.Image> images = nativeContentAd.getImages();

    if (images.size() > 0) {
        ((ImageView) adView.getImageView()).setImageDrawable(images.get(0).getDrawable());
    }

    // Some aren't guaranteed, however, and should be checked.
    NativeAd.Image logoImage = nativeContentAd.getLogo();

    if (logoImage == null) {
        adView.getLogoView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ((ImageView) adView.getLogoView()).setImageDrawable(logoImage.getDrawable());
        adView.getLogoView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // Assign native ad object to the native view.
    adView.setNativeAd(nativeContentAd);
}
```

}

I am not able to figure out where to keep to check and how to add native ads in between the items of my gridview (recyclerview).

Layout of my discover item where I am having a framelayout. In this framelayout I am loading the native ads.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_discover_icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/events" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.erbauen.widgets.MyTextView_medium
                android:id="@+id/tv_discover_heading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/item_event_detail"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:lines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="Network over Coffee"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/events_item_date_time"

                />

            <com.erbauen.widgets.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_author_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/item_event_detail"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Network over Coffee"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/events_item_date_time"

                />

            <com.erbauen.widgets.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/item_discover_descrip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/item_event_heading"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:fontFamily="Helvetica"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="Brief information about the event. Brief information about the event. Brief information about the event."
                android:textSize="@dimen/events_item_date_time"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/light_green">

    </View>-->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I removed the framelayout from the discover_item.xml. Now how to hide and unhide the respective layouts ?

Comment: please post your row layout xml

Comment: Please refresh. I have updated the question with the xml file

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove ad from your card layout or alternatively you can hide and show your views on the basis of row number.

And you need to create a different cardlayout with ad only and need to show it for every 3rd position from your onBindViewHolder method

```
if (position % 3 == 0) {
    // inflate your ad view here or hide your normal native view here and show ad view
} else {
     // inflate your normal native view here or hide your ad view here and show normal native view
}
```

Comment: please can you try?

Comment: I want to a native ad in between my gridview items

Comment: do you want alternate rows? one with native view and one with ad?

Comment: Actually I want in every 3rd position

Comment: than you are doing it wrong, you need to remove ad from your card layout, and you need to create a different cardlayout with ad only and need to show it for every (position % 3 == 0) from your onBindViewHolder method.

Comment: Ok. Let me try this.

Comment: I have updated the code & existing xml . Now how to hide and unhide the respective layouts in onBindViewholder

Comment: You can call view.setVisibility(View.GONE) if you want to remove it from the layout.
Or view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) if you just want to hide it.
And view.setVisibility(View.SHOW) if you just want to show it.

Comment: But in OnBindViewHolder , I am passing MyViewHolder & position as parameters. There is no view.

Comment: you need to inflate two views and pass those both two to your viewholder inside onCreateViewHolder() method and than in your onBindViewHolder() method you need to get those view from view holder and call show or hide method whichever is required.

Comment: I inflated 2 views but in onBindViewHolder method, how to get those view from viewholder. Can you tell me exactly, by referring the above code which I have posted.